# Locking Columns in Google Sheets when a cell reaches a number

Tags: google-sheets, locking

I am creating a spreadsheet to be used among 40 teachers to assign students to a variety of classes. Student names are in rows while the classes are in columns. As students join a class, there is a cell in the column that adds the total number of students who have joined the class. When the class reaches a specific number, I would like the column to change colors to indicate the class is full or completely lock the column so no more students may be added. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Richard, if you just want to colour the column, you could try conditional formatting like so:

1. Pick the range of columns you want to be colour coded
2. Apply the custom formula `=B$1>3`. This means that for each column in the range, the formula will look at the first row in that column - that is why the `$` is in front of the row number and not the column letter - and if that number is greater than 3 (class capacity), then the column will turn red(ish).

[image: Conditional formatting]

But if you want to lock the column, you'll need to get into Google Apps Script.